# Using state in react as a json key value inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, syntax, key

I'm trying to use a state as a key for a json in a react project and it's showing up an error, i can't figure out why (i think it's a syntax error with the map function inside {}).
Here is the code, i want to use **dynamicState** inside a map function :

```js
import dataJson from "./data/data.json"

function App() {  
 
  const [dynamicState, setDynamicState] = useState("EN");
  const dataArray = dataJson;

  return ( 
  <div>

    <div className="container">   
      {dataArray.dynamicState.map((estacion, index) => {
        return (
          
          <div className="cardEstacion" key={estacion.id}>
            <h2 class="cardTitle">{estacion.title}</h2>
            <p class="cardSubtitle">{estacion.subTitle}</p>
          </div>
          
        )
      })
      }      
    </div>
    

  </div>
  );
}
```

here is my data.json file:

```json
{
    "ES": [        
        {
            "id": 0,
            "audio": "",
            "images": [...],
            "title": "",
            "subTitle": "",            
            "body": ""            
        }            
    ],
    "EN" : [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "audio": "",
            "images": [...],
            "title": "",
            "subTitle": "",            
            "body": ""            
        }   
    ]
}
```

My solution was to convert the data to an array with `const dataArray = Object.values(dataJson)` and then using it inside the map function with [0] or [1] if i want to reference ES or EN key `dataArray[0].map((estacion, index))` but i feel that a dynamic key is a better approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) for dynamic keys `{dataArray[dynamicState]map(`

Comment: Oh, i searched for about 2 hours for that because i didnt wanted to be an ask to ask :facePalm: https://dontasktoask.com/.
Thank you x1000 @pilchard

Comment: Heh, no worries!